# Checking the last signal sent to your application

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

I want to be able to break out of the while loop when a signal is sent. I'm unsure how to accomplish this without using a global variable or writing to a file. Would my best bet to be using a semaphore?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void random()
{
    printf("random!");
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, random);

    // I want this while loop to break if random executes
    while (1)
    {
        pause();
    }
    // do more stuff after loop

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this specific case, just removing the loop would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pause` blocks until a signal is received that calls a signal handler, so you could just add a `break;` after the `pause();` to exit the loop.  So you might as well get rid of the loop altogether.

If what you want to do is NOT wait, but instead loop doing something and only exit when the signal occurs, you can't use `pause`.  The obvious way is to use a global variable, but you say you want to avoid that.  An alternative that isn't really any simpler is to use `sigprocmask`/`sigpending` instead of a signal handler:

```
int main()
{
    setset_t  signals;
    sigemptyset(&signals);
    sigaddset(&signals, SIGINT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signals, 0);  /* block SIGINT */

    while (1) {
        /* do stuff */
        sigpending(&signals);
        if (sigismember(&signals, SIGINT)) {
            /* got a SIGINT */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main function isn't doing anything after the loop, except exiting.  I understand this may be simplified code to ask the question.  But if you're actually not doing anything after the loop you want to break from, then just change your sig handler function to this:

```
void random(int sig)
{
    printf("random!");
    exit(sig);  // or exit(0); as in your main()
}
```

On the other hand, if you need to communicate between `random` (handler) and `main` then why are you reluctant to use a variable?

Comment: I would like the program to continue executing after the loop, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer really depends on what you're going to be doing in the loop. I'll assume `pause()` is simply fake code as an example since it's not useful.

If your loop is an event loop that waits with `select` or `poll`, you could switch to `pselect` (standard in POSIX) or `ppoll` (a nonstandard extension, but better since the `select` API is so bad) that which will also let you wait for signals. But you're still stuck with how to get the notification that the signal occurred. With just one signal, you could use the fact that `EINTR` was returned to infer that `SIGINT` happened, but this doesn't work so well if there could be other signal handlers too. Basically, signal handling is fundamentally *global*, and as such, global variables/global state have to be involved in some way. You could store a flag that the signal happened in a global variable and check it each time `pselect`/`ppoll` returns, **or** you could just stick with plain standard `poll` and use the [self-pipe trick](http://lwn.net/Articles/177897/) since you need to be doing something with global state in your signal handler anyway.

If your loop is not waiting for events but constantly spinning (e.g. a computational loop) then just blocking the signal (with `sigprocmask` or `pthread_sigmask`) and periodically checking for it with `sigispending` or `sigwaitinfo` is a simple solution that doesn't require any code in the signal handler.